# How to display content ignoring the parent padding

Tags: html, css

This is a table,

[image]

This is the design of the same table when `onHover`

[image]

Here is the trouble, the parent div of the original div has a `padding` to align the table content, so when onHover, the `background-color` is following the same constraint as well. So it becomes this:

[image]

How to solve this, how to make it break the padding constraint?

I created a [codepen](https://codepen.io/vensa-albertgao/pen/yZKKXa)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this?

```css
.box {
  background-color: lightgrey;

}

.row {
  display: flex;
  padding: 16px;
}

.row:hover {
  background-color:red;
}

.cell {
  width: 33%;
}
```

```html
<div class='box'>
  <div class='row'>
    <div class='cell'>
      1
    </div>
    <div class='cell'>
      2
    </div>
    <div class='cell'>
      3
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Silly me, just as easy as adding padding to the row

Answer (score 0):

Put left/right padding on .cell like this:

```
    .cell {
      width: 33%;
      padding: 0 1rem;
    }
```

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/wNmmxa

Answer (score 0):

How about adding this to your css?

```
.box:hover{background-color: red;}
```

https://codepen.io/vensa-albertgao/pen/yZKKXa

Comment: Thanks, but that will cause the whole table to be colored when one of its children been hovered :(